# Scaling background pattern fill in html5 canvas tag

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, html5-canvas, scaling

I have a canvas tag displaying a set of paths and rectangles.

I zoom into these paths and rectangles by using the ctx.scale(2,2) function and then redraw them with the new scale so they are sharp.

I would like to have a simple textured background for some of the rectangles, i.e. one pixel black one white, however when I apply the texture as a fill to the scaled rectangle, canvas scales the background pattern as well. I would like the background pattern to remain at the original scale of one pixel black, one pixel white. But cannot seem to figure out how to do this with it looking blurry. I have a example here : http://jsfiddle.net/4UxWg/

```
var patternCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var pattern_ctx = patternCanvas.getContext("2d");
patternCanvas.width = 1;
patternCanvas.height = 2;

pattern_ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);


var mainCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");
mainCanvas.height = 500;
mainCanvas.width = 400;

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(mainCanvas);

//scale function - remove this line to see how the pattern should look like
ctx.scale(5,5); 

var pattern = ctx.createPattern(patternCanvas, "repeat");
ctx.fillStyle= pattern;

ctx.fillRect(2,2,40,40); //fillRect looks wierd and pattern is no longer 1px by 1px
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi, sorry, not sure I understand - wouldn't that just scale the background as in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** I read background as the global background behind all the shapes. But it seem to be the *fill* of the shapes if I now understand it correctly - in that case you need to do things slightly different:

To keep filled pattern unaffected by scaled dimensions of the shapes you will need to manually scale the shapes -

Either:

```
var scale = 5;

ctx.fillRect(x * scale, y * scale, w * scale, h * scale);
```

or use a wrapper function:

```
function fillRectS(x, y, w, h) {
    ctx.fillRect(x * scale, y * scale, w * scale, h * scale);
}

fillRectS(x, y, w, h);
```

For stroke you just do the same:

```
function lineWidthS(w) {
    ctx.lineWidth = w * scale;
}
```

and so forth (lines, moveTo, arc). This will allow you to scale all shapes but keep pattern fill at 1:1 ratio. The overhead will be minimal.

**Old answer** -

There are at least two ways around this:

**1)** You can reset the translation when you fill the pattern and then re-apply transformations right after.

```
/// reset
ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

ctx.scale(sx, sy);
```

**2)** Layer the canvases so that the background is drawn separately on one canvas and use the top canvas to draw in anything else that needs to be drawn in scale.

Different scales and transformations used simultaneously is one good case scenario to use layered canvas.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="bg" ... ></canvas>
    <canvas id="main" ... ></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    }
#container > canvas {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    }
```

Then get context for each and draw in as needed (pseudo-ish):

```
var bgCtx = bg.getContext('2d');
var ctx = main.getContext('2d');

... other setup code here ...

/// will only affect foreground canvas
ctx.scale(5, 5);

/// will only fill background canvas
bgCtx.fillStyle = pattern;
bgCtx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
```

Now these won't affect each other.

Comment: Thanks for the options! Can you elaborate a bit on the first? If I understood correctly - I should do the scale after the fillRect - but in this case the rectangle won't scale? I updated the jsfiddle but couldn't see how to make it work?

Comment: @SimonKenyonShepard ah, my bad. I read background as the global background. In the case you need to *fill* the rectangle with the background not being affected by scale you will need to scale the elements manually, ie. `fillRect(x * scale, y * scale, width * scale, height * scale)` etc. and only use .scale() for the other shapes (or scale them to manually). You can easily make wrapper functions that do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

The returned [CanvasPattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasPattern) has a [setTransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasPattern/setTransform) method. In this way you can avoid having to use a separate canvas as a pattern. Just scale the pattern in the opposite direction.

Answer (score -1):

For posterity, I wrote a Context2D wrapper that automatically does this and adds some tracking/debugging features to help you draw. It doesn't actually sacrifice any performance!

You can find it here: https://github.com/LemonPi/Context2DTracked

Or if you're using npm (with webpack or something) `npm install context-2d-tracked`